# AJAX / PHP form submit issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I trying to upgrade a website to make it easily replicable and more database driven.

My forms use PHP / AJAX to submit to response.php within the same directory.

E.G domain.com/client1/login.php this would use JS in /js/common.js

common.js will take the variables from the form name and use domain.com/client1/response.php?action=login

The issue I am having is that despite login.php and response.php both being in client1/, the JS is trying to locate response.php at domain.com/response.php

Is there a way of forcing the JS to use the local directory or taking my php url: '$isteURL/response.php',

Any help would be gratefully appreciate, racking my head here.

$siteURL is defined in the header.php above the JS file

```
    function submitForm3() {        
    var data = $("#reset-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({                
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '<?php echo $siteURL; ?>/response.php?action=reset',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#reset_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
        },
        success : function(response){           
            if($.trim(response) === "1"){
                console.log('dddd');                                    
                $("#reset-submit").html('Email sent ...');
                setTimeout(' window.location.href = "index.php?resetStatus=1"; ',2000);
            } else {                                    
                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){                        
                    $("#error").html(response).show();
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "$siteURL is defined in the header.php above the JS file" ... therefore you need to copy/paste header.php in your question as well.

Comment: Did you check your common.js source? `PHP` usually isn't being parsed in `.js` files, unless you tell your webserver to do so

Comment: common.js source is above. I can post the full page but this is the relevant bit. When I change remove the echo and just place in client1/response... works fine. When I just leave response.php and check the consol it has a 404 error on response .php.

Comment: in relation to header I can do but. $siteURL works fine on the rest of the site, I just can't bring it into the JS. I would rather no be passing php variables in the JS, my preference is for it to use the documents in the directory it is in

Comment: "_common.js source is above_" I meant did you view the file on your server, from the source of the page, like http://localhost/js/common.js? Did `<?php echo $siteURL; ?>` actually run and place your siteURL in `common.js`? Or is `<?php echo $siteURL; ?>` still there? As said, `PHP` is usually only parsed/run in `.php` files, not `.js`

Comment: NO it doesn't link to file is https://volunteershub.co.uk/vmsmain/js/common.js - the idea being that vmsmain will be replicated to several different sites so I want it be able to $siteURL to make the site easier to set up

Comment: Php code is only executed in `.php` files

Comment: Why don't you use a JavaScript variable for this then? Add `<script>const baseURL = '...';</script>` before any of the other scripts - and output the value via PHP, dynamically. Then all your other scripts can use that variable, to build the full URL for the specific request.